# What are the common characteristics in occam and csp?

Tags: parallel-processing, occam-pi

I saw a question while I was studying for OCCAM and CSP ( Communicating Sequential Processes ). I found some basic answers like;

- they both for parallel programming,
- they get input with question mark(?),
- send output with exclamation mark(!).

But I want to find out more technical details about their common features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### On CSP

Hoare's CSP was completed during 1979 ~ 1984, when his [**Book on CSP** ( today having some 260+ pages )](http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf) was first published in 1985.

This final version of CSP also includes channels, that allow process-to-process communication and synchronisation mechanics.

### On `occam`

David May, along with Hoare's team at Oxford, has concurrently with the evolution of CSP developed **`occam`**, a language tightly knit to the **InMOS** very innovative and very advanced **TRANSPUTER** processor-networks, deliberately intended to blend CSP into a practical programming language.

There are un-"paralleled" advanced features of the `occam` language concept that contemporary languages may source from.

A funny sample code (C) 2000, Fred Barnes with some fixes/mods from Peter Welch illustrates the powers of the language/CSP channel concepts on a toy example of a Bar-simulator, serving beers, while keeping the code readable and expressive.

```
-- ...(cleared for clarity >>> http://frmb.org/download/bar.occ )
-- ..
-- .
--{{{
PROC        bar.tender ( []CHAN OF BYTE  req, rsp,
                           CHAN OF INT   mode.change,
                           CHAN OF O.REQ d.chan,
                           SEMAPHORE     d.sem,
                           CHAN OF BOOL  kill
                           )
  CHAN OF BYTE spinal.chord:
  CHAN OF BOOL kill.brain, kill.body:

  PAR
    --{{{  terminator SEQ, BUT DECLARED TO RUN IN TRUE-PARALLEL EXEC WITH bar.brain() & bar.body()
    BOOL any:
    SEQ                   -- SEQ:
      kill ? any
      kill.brain ! any    -- order is
      kill.body ! any     -- important
    --}}}
    bar.brain ( req, spinal.chord, mode.change, kill.brain )
    bar.body  ( spinal.chord, rsp, d.chan, d.sem, kill.body )
:
--}}}
```

In next waves, CSP and Occam have influenced each other ( for example in [**The Laws of Occam Programming** ( ~90 pages, scanned copy )](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3376/PRG53.pdf)  ), touching as advanced topics as [**distributed real-time processing** and many other advanced fields of interest.](https://books.google.cz/books?id=Pi2W6hjHb1sC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=Distributed%20occam&source=bl&ots=aMt81jZ4XO&sig=yx4EDYs-D0jYyNCe0gzdVeJJrtw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V8aQVciSMYGkUO73hKgP&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Distributed%20occam&f=false)