# Which concurrency models do multi-process/thread programming belong to?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, programming-languages, multiprocess

[Wikipedia C/S article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)#Models) says

> A number of formalisms for modeling and understanding **concurrent
>   systems** have been developed, including:[5]
>
> ```
> The parallel random-access machine[6]
> The actor model
> Computational bridging models such as the bulk synchronous parallel (BSP) model
> Petri nets
> Process calculi
>     Calculus of communicating systems (CCS)
>     Communicating sequential processes (CSP) model
>     π-calculus
> Tuple spaces, e.g., Linda
> Simple Concurrent Object-Oriented Programming (SCOOP)
> Reo Coordination Language
> ```

Which model(s) do multi-process programming (as in Linux API, MPI, Java, Python) belong to?

Which model(s) do multi-threading programming (as in PThread, Java, Python) belong to?

Answer (score 3):

Let me add I bit of thoughts:

[**`occam-pi`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41397734/3666197) is true-`[PARALLEL]` language well fit onto parallel InMos T-414 Transputer hardware ( actually a hardware network of Transputers ). Process-flow was based on the theory of lambda-calculus guaranteed scheduling strategy and coordination was thanks to the seminal work of Hoarre's CSP not a constraint to achieving a true-`[PARALLEL]` execution, pure-`[SERIAL]` execution ( where feasible ) and opportunistic "just"-`[CONCURRENT]`, where required.

So the language ( paradigm ) does not uniquely map onto some above Wikipedia listed archetype form of parallelism. Also the external code-execution eco-system properties matter.

**Python,** on the other hand, is since the Guido Rossum's design decision a pure sequential interpreter process ( whatever amount of threads one might have instantiated, as the central Global Interpreter Lock, the GIL-lock, knowingly chops the flow of time and permits one and only one thread to execute, all others waiting for GIL, thus the code principally avoids any form of a just-`[CONCURRENT]` related collisions ( race condition to acquire a resource, read(s) colliding with write(s) et al ).

Python **can** use message passing using **`MPI`** or ZeroMQ, can use a CSP paradigm module, has modules that enjoy the actor-model behaviour ( as an example in, mimicking the XEROX PARC-place invention of a **M**odel-**V**isual-**C**ontroller coordination ) so the language typically does not constrain a paradigm, being used on a higher layer of abstraction ( while the lower level constraints do limit how hard-real-time any such abstracted form of execution may get harnessed, as any low-level limitations extend all upper abstraction-layers latency and may introduce fine-grain blocking state(s), that are outside of a domain of control of the upper-layer abstracted code-execution behaviour(s) )

Python **can** use **`multiprocessing`** ( `joblib` decorated or not ) - it helped to partially escape from the principal, and as Guido Rossum has expressed on his own that GIL-lock will remain a natural part of the python interpreter, unless an immense scale of total re-design of the whole concept of the interpreter is undertaken (which is not, in his view, a probable direction of further efforts spent in this domain). Attempts to escape from the otherwise, known and forever present principal GIL-lock orchestrated re-`[SERIAL]`-isation of any number of threads execution were developed, yet each one comes at a cost - **human-related:** refactoring the code, **system-related:** re-spawning the full-identical copies of the original python interpreter state ( the only chance under Windows-class O/S-es, partial or ad-hoc copies in linux `fork` or `forkserver` ), making troubles for both newbies and practitioners by ignoring or wrong guesses of the Amdahl Law add-on costs added right due to process-instantiation costs ( TIME + RAM-allocations TIME + RAM-to-RAM copy TIME + parameters / interprocess SER/DES-add-on TIME ), sum of which may easily wipe up any promises or wished-to-have speedups from going into a "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** or a true-**`[PARALLEL]`** code-execution domain.

Python **can**, as most of the other mentioned examples, participate in a **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)**-infrastructure, where higher-layer paradigms control the mode-of-cooperative execution, so the macro-system may have higher-levels of concurrency, not visible from "inside" a python-node.

The above-listed "forms"-of are sort of academic ( missing a hardware-based ILP-parallelism, AND-based and OR-based forms of fine-grain forms of parallelisms ), PRAM-s being the subject of C/S research as deep as in late 60-ies, early 70-ies, when it was concluded that even PRAM-based architectures cannot escape from Class-2 computing taxonomy.

> "***Section 4.3*** <sub>( IS THERE ANY CHANCE FOR A GIANT LEAP )</sub> **BEYOND THE CLASS-2 COMPUTER BOUNDARIES** [2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)
>
> *The main practical - though negative - implication of the previous thoughts is a fact
>   that within the Class-2 computing, there is not to be expected any efficient solution
>   for sequentially intractable problems.*
>
> *Nevertheless, a question raises here, whether some other sort of parallel computers could be imaginable,
>   that would be computationally more efficient than Class-2 computers.*
>
> *Indications, coming from many known, conceptually different C2 class computer models,
>   suggest that without adding some other, fundamental computing capability, the parallelism per se
>   does not suffice to overcome C2 class boundaries,
>   irrespective how we try to modify, within all thinkable possibilites,
>   the architectures of such computers.*
>
> *As a matter of fact, it turns out, that C2 class boundaries will be crossed,
>   if there would be a non-determinism added to an MIMD-type parallelism ( Ref. Section 3.5 ).*
>
> *Non-deterministic PRAM (+)
>   can, as an example, solve ( intractable ) problems from NPTIME class
>   in polylogarithmic time and problems of a demonstrably exponential sequential complexity in polynomial time.*
>
> *Because, in the context of computers, where the non-determinism is equally well technically feasible to be implemented
>   as a clairvoyance, the C2 computer class seems to represent, from the efficiency point of view,
>   the ultimate class for the parallel computers, the borders of which will never be crossed.*
>
> *+) PRAM: a Parallel-RAM, not a SIMD-only processor, demonstrated by Savitch, Stimson in 1979 (1)*
>
> *(1) SAVITCH, W. J. - STIMSON, M. J.: Time bounded random access machines with parallel processing. J. ACM 26, 1979, Pg. 103-118.
>
>   (2) WIEDERMANN, J.: Efficiency boundaries of parallel computing systems. ( Medze efektivnosti paralelných výpočtových systémov ).
>   Advances in Mathematics, Physics and Astronomy ( Pokroky matematiky, fyziky a astronomie ), Vol. 33 (1988), No. 2, Pg. 81--94*"

Both a process-based and a thread-based code may per-se use, or participate in a gang-of-coordinated actors in almost any of the above enlisted forms-of-concurrency.

The code-implementation plus all the underlying resources' management constraints ( hardware + O/S + resource-management policy in respective context of use ) actually decide about what forms remain achievable in fields, when and how any piece of code gets executed - i.e., your code design may be of any level of geniality architecture-wise, if O/S policy resorts your code to get executed on a one only and the only one CPU-core ( due to user-process effective rights enforced affinity mapping constraints ), again any such smart-code will result in a re-**`[SERIAL]`**-ised code-execution ( paying all the [**add-on** overhead costs](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) of wished-to-have **`[CONCURRENT]`**-execution, but getting nothing in return of having spent and continuing to spend such add-on costs ) the very like the straightforward, pure-**`[SERIAL]`** code does [ which one also remains free from any wasted add-on costs, so results in a faster result generation, often with also enjoying a benefit of non-depleted CPU-core local L1/L2 cache hierarchies, if HPC-grade computing was carefully designed-in :o) ]

Comment: @halfer Was that "*director's cut*" necessary? **What new level of understanding did it introduce**, after that part of the text was removed? Do we try to save cents (on storage) "in exchange" for loosing the dollars (in knowledge & its whole context)? ***Hope you have a stronger reason to delete the parts of the human knowledge***. IMHO Ms. HAMILTON's story is second in saving mankind's future, second to a story of dis-obeyance of the Line-of-Command & SOPs for nuclear warheads launch in the late 70-ies, yet that was a unique man/moment,whereas Ms.HAMILTON's methods last & are repeatable

Comment: Undoubtedly there are many people in the CS world who have made heroic achievements. I am quite convinced, however, that Stack Overflow is not the proper place for such biographical asides. Succinctness is greatly valued here.